# Helper function in vuex actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose I have a method in

```js
const actions = {
  async fetchByQuery({
    commit
  }, title) {
    const response = await..........code goes here
  }
}
```

And I want to use my own another function inside the method like this:

```js
        const actions = {
          async fetchByQuery({
            commit
          }, title) {
            const response = await..........code goes here
            
            this.helperfunction();
          }
          
          helperfunction(){
             ......code goes here
          }
        }
```

How go I get to use helper function ?

I tried above method and got error **this.helperfunction is not a function**

Answer (score 1):

You can always import functions outside of the store, they don't have to be part of it.

```
// Either

import HelperFunction from "./helperfunction.js

// OR:

const HelperFunction = () => {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}

const actions = {
  async fetchByQuery({
    commit
  }, title) {
    const response = await..........code goes here
    
    // Use the helper function without `this`
    let formattedResponse = HelperFunction(response);
    
    commit('saveState', formattedResponse); 
  }
  
}
```

It's worth noting that they won't have direct access to modify the store, however it might be just what you need. Its difficult to say without knowing the context of your question.

Comment: To explain in short `fetchByQuery` function gets the html data of any given site  in HTML format (webscrapping) and I've been doing all sort of search tags and filter required data task with in the function. So I wanted to breakdown the search and filter into their respective methods. THat's all

Comment: @PawanRai Yes, I think you should be able to use what I've written above to achieve this.